# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package - Only getting error while in vscode but not pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pycharm

This is what my file structure looks like

```
assignment
|
|__ qn1
|    |__ qn1.py
|    
|__ qn1
     |__ qn2.py
```

This is the simplified content of qn1.py

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def method(self):
    pass
```

This is the simplified content of qn2.py

```
from qn1.qn1 import A
```

This works perfectly in pycharm but I can't seem to get it to work in vscode and I get this error message

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qn1'**

I also tried using these import lines

```
from ..qn1.qn1 import A
from ..qn1 import qn1; qn1.A
```

but I get this error for both

**ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package**

I also tried adding

```
__init__.py
```

into the directory qn1 but it did not seem to help.

Not using vscode is not an option as the school requires me to submit it through an online vscode editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path to qn1") 
import qn1
```

have a look at this website for some more guidance: https://linuxhint.com/sys-path-append-python/
In essence, sys.path.append adds the directory to where python looks for libraries (which is how qn1 will be treated).

Comment: Thank you for answering. This worked on the vscode on my machine but as I have to submit the code through an online version of vscode(VM), I am unable to use the absolute path.

Do you know of any other solutions?

Comment: what IDE are you using - is it github.dev?

Comment: I'm using vocareum labs through my school's website

Comment: Unfortunately, that's paid software - I can't test it out. I'd consider checking their docs or equivalent because I think it's an issue with their VM as supposed to your code.

Comment: I'll do that, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: It turns out that I was using the wrong path in vocareum labs sincei copied the path from the terminal which was 'labsuser@desktop:~/Submission/qn1' but running 'pwd' in the terminal gave me the actual working path which made your solution work for me. Thanks!